# setTimeout keeps running after clearTimeout has been called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout, cleartimeout

I am animating an object to move to 1 direction while the mouse is down and when the mouse clic goes up, the animation should stop.

I'm using setTimeout but it keeps moving for some time after I released the clic.

```
var stopmov
function tomove(){
    $('.plwid').animate({
        left: '+=1'
    },1);
    stopmov=setTimeout(function(){ tomove(); }, 1);
}

$('.plwid').mouseup(function(){
    clearTimeout(stopmov);
}).mousedown(function(){
    tomove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oa9bsqy1/

Comment: You need to check if the mouse is down, not queue up thousands of callbacks from your recursive setTimeout call.

Comment: You don't need anonymous function wrappers. You can use `setTimeout(tomove, 1)` and `mousedown(tomove)`.

Comment: @MattBurland Why is that problematic? Each timer only creates a new timer: the next one. So cancelling the last timer will stop the animation. The problem is that the last timer is not always canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played around with `setTimeout` and `setInterval` but I think it's better to use a recursive call in the done callback of jQuery animate.

Also stopping is then pretty easy with `$('.plwid').stop();`.

Please find the demo below and here at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/8q0x28se/).

```js
function tomove() {
    $('.plwid').animate({
        left: '+=10'
    },
    100, 'linear', tomove);
}

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    $('.plwid').stop();
});

$('.plwid').mousedown(function () {
    tomove();
});
```

```css
.plwid {
    position:relative;
    left:10px;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plwid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off adding the moueup on the document and not the element.

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clearTimeout(stopmov);
});
$('.plwid').mousedown(function(){
    tomove();
});
```

other issue is the 1 millisecond you are using is geneterating tons of hits, you need to pick a more reasonable number.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mouseIsDown = false;

function tomove(){
  $('.plwid').animate({
    left: '+=1'
  },1);
  if(mouseIsDown) setTimeout(function(){ tomove(); }, 1);
}

$('.plwid').mousedown(function(){
  mouseIsDown = true;
  tomove();
});
$(document).mouseup(function(){
  mouseIsDown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like every time tomove runs, it runs settimeout again, and the stopmov variable will only have the very most recent ...

So, just take

```
stopmov=setTimeout(function(){ tomove(); }, 1);
```

out of the first function.  Call the settimeout when you're mousing down.

```
var stopmov
function tomove(){
    $('.plwid').animate({
        left: '+=1'
},1);
}
$('.plwid').mouseup(function(){
    clearTimeout(stopmov);
}).mousedown(function(){
    stopmov=setTimeout(function(){ tomove(); }, 1);
});
```

Comment: But then there won't be any animation. Just a single pixel move per click.

Comment: oh right... I was getting setTimeout confused with setInterval.  Have you tried setInterval, instead?